# Load a back directory with Ext.Loader.require

Tags: extjs, extjs4

Consider I have defined this namespace `Boo` as this path `/Plugins/Content/App`.
Now I need to load a script with `Ext.Loader.require` from `/Plugins/Content`.

How can I load a content from a backward folder with `Boo` namespace? Is there any solution like `Ext.Loader.require("Boo/../")` that set the cursor to `/Plugins/Content`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I never tried that but you should be able to archive this with **[setPath()](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.Loader-method-setPath)** for your defined namespace. After that you can use `Ext.Loader.require()` on a class of this namespace.

To take credit to the comments:

**No**, this isn't possible.

> The **ClassManager** will not be able to identify a possible classname and
>   will so not be able to find a possible namespace to use for loading.

**Why?**

The ClassManager does not take care about the nav part `/../` which would then cause problems

Comment: Of course yes, but as I said, I have one namespace and I want to load other contents with that namespace.

Comment: @AfshinMehrabani No you can't do it this way cause the require method uses the name `"Boo/../"` to lookup the classname.

Comment: Don't you think this is a limitation of ExtJs?

Comment: @AfshinMehrabani Actually you can name it as you like ;) I took a look a the sourcecode of the loader and I already know the ClassManager. It is simply not possible the way things work. The ClassManager will not be able to identify a possible classname and will so not be able to find a possible namespace. With limitation you mean that the classmanger / loader not removes the nav part `/../` and add it later? I guess this is a domain specific usecase and therefore not included.